# Laravel Many to Many relationship

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4

I have 3 tables

- Item (Belongs to Many Tag)
- Tag (Belongs to Many Item)
- Item_Tag(contains item_id & tag_id)

I'm trying to use ORM to retrieve the Tags from Item

```
$itemTags = Item::find($itemID)->tags;
```

Returns `object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#203 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }`

If i add ()

```
$itemTags = Item::find($itemID)->tags();
```

I get a long page of stuff.

How do i grab the tags that is related to this item?

Model Tag

```
<?php

class Tag extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('tag');
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Item');
    }


}
```

Model Item

```
<?php

class Item extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('title', 'price','user_id');


    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
    }
}
```

Comment: `$itemTags = Item::find($itemID)->tags();` unless I am missing something obvious, this already contains the tags for the item with `$itemID`!

Comment: ^ assuming he has a hasMany relationship in his Item eloquent model...

Comment: I have both Belongs to Many only

Comment: Can we see your model code?

Comment: I think it's because you need to declare your table names since they aren't following standards.  Try adding `protected $table = 'Item'` to the `Item` model and `protected $table = 'Tag`;` to the `Tag` model.

Answer (score 0):

"A long page of stuff" is just the relational object. You don't need that.

`$itemTags = Item::find($itemID)->tags;` is enough

If that returns `object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#203 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }` it just means you have an Eloquent Collection of 0 objects. In other words, the relationship works fine there are just no tags (yet).

Answer (score 0):

You need to eager-load the relationship data first, I think.

```
$item = Item::with('tags')->find($itemID);
$tags = $item->tags;
```